# how do I display data from a count() query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running this query and getting results:

```
|  COUNT(DISTINCT member_extension)  |  queue_name        |  queue_account_id
|  21                                |     Standard       |  1105
|  16                                |     Premium        |  1133
|  21                                |     WorldMark      |  1202
|  8                                 |     Escalation     |  1248
|  17                                |     Wingate Queue  |  1249
```

However, I can't seem to display the member_extension COUNT() total when I try to put them in a table. What am I doing wrong?

I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: member_extension in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phone-dashboard\testing\count_test.php on line 59

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT member_extension),     queue_name,`queue_account_id`
FROM CallLog
WHERE type = 'completed'
BETWEEN '2013-10-22 09:00:00'
AND '2013-10-24 09:00:00'
GROUP BY queue_account_id
"); 
$sth->execute();
$sql = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<table>';
echo "<tr><td>" . 'Queue Name' . "</td><td>" . 'Queue Account ID' . "</td><td>" . 'Queue Total' . "</td></tr>";
try {   
    foreach ($sql as $rs) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $rs['queue_name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $rs['queue_account_id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $rs['member_extension'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        }

    echo '</table>';
    }
catch (PDOException $e) {
print $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: The result set ($rs) does not contain a column named "member_extension".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the count an alias that you can easily refer to:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT member_extension) AS num_extensions


foreach ($sql as $rs) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $rs['queue_name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $rs['queue_account_id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $rs['num_extensions'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
```